# Differential inequality implies estimation

Tags: inequality

From the inequality
\begin{equation}
y^\prime(t) + C_1 y^\alpha(t) \le C_2, \quad y(0) = y_0
\end{equation}
for $t \in (0,T)$ and constants $C_1,C_2, \alpha > 0$,
I want to imply
\begin{equation}
y(t) \le \max\left\{y_0,\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)^{\frac1\alpha}\right\}
\end{equation}
for all $t \in (0,T)$.

I tried to do separation of variables with the transformation $z:=y^\alpha$, but I didn't get the above estimation.

Does someone know how to do this?

For $\alpha = 1$ this is contained in the proof of Lemma 4.5 in https://math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/mathematik/ag-partielle-differentialgleichungen/Publikationen/Winkler/2020/winkler_2d_KS_NaSto_repulsion_homepage.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ can not grow indefinitely, if $y'\ge 0$ then obviously $y^α\le \frac{C_2}{C_1}$, so that $y$ can not grow above $\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)^\frac1α$. On the other hand, if $y'<0$ on an initial segment, then $y$ is falling, so also $y\le y_0$ there. While a falling segment can be followed by an increasing segment, the first restriction will kick in, so that in total really $$y(x)\le\max\left(y_0,\left(\frac{C_2}{C_1}\right)^\frac1α\right).$$